# What is the best way to edit (insert variables) multiple different files in Python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, erb

I have 2 files:`body.html.erb` and `page.json` and I use them as templates.

The `body.html.erb` has a lot of content (1033 lines) while the JSON file only has 2 objects.

I want to be able to edit the contents with Python, is it possible?

For example:

##### Python variables

```
py_name = "John Doe"
py_path = "/john-doe"
```

##### page.json

```
{
    "name": py_name, 
    "path": py_path
}
```

##### body.html.erb

```
<% pame = py_name %>
<% path = py_path %>
```

Is this possible at all? Would I have to convert these files to `.txt` files first for them to be editable, insert the variables, then convert them back to `.erb` and `.json` files? What would be the best way to go about this?

### Edit (temporary solution)

What I've done is do: `{{ py_name }}` and {{ py_path }} inside the JSON and ERB files, then I did:

```
.replace("{{ py_name }}", py_name).replace("{{ py_path }}", py_path)
```

Is there a better way to do this or is this the only easy way?

Comment: If you do convert it into text, complicated text replacement patterns are definitely possible using RegularExpressions. I would advise going through the regexp tutorial at https://regexone.com/, then try stuff out with https://regex101.com/ and implement it in python using the [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module

Comment: I don't find your question very clear, but you may be looking for *"Jinja templating"*, example here https://ttl255.com/jinja2-tutorial-part-1-introduction-and-variable-substitution/